# How to program LEGO Mindstorms EV3 using C language?

Tags: c, sensors, robotics, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

First of all, I'm new for this and I need a little help!

I have a LEGO Mindstorms EV3 robot, I downloaded (LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Home Edition) to control the EV3. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the source code for the EV3 in the mentioned software. So, please if anybody could tell me the name of the software that enables you to program EV3! I would be most appreciated!

I also downloaded (Bricxcc) software but it was an old version. I couldn't find a newer version which contains EV3.

Can I use C language to program EV3 ? Or to add some features to the sensors?

Note: I ended with leJOS software to program the code with java it is much easier and there are a lot of resources for the EV3 brick in java. Wish you all the best!

Comment: Just a tip: 'robots.txt' is not the tag you want. It's not about robots, it's about web.

Answer (score 13):

You can find the EV3 source code here: https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources

The generated documentation from this source code is available [here](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/index.html) and [here](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen-all/).

Bricxcc has some experimental support for EV3 but it is not being actively developed (since Oct. 2013). You can find the latest test version [here](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/test_releases/). Searching the web for "bricxcc ev3" will come up with some tutorials (for example, the one at http://www.robotnav.com looks good).

[ROBOTC](http://www.robotc.net/) is a good alternative, although it is not free.

There is also [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org). There is a C library for ev3dev [here](https://github.com/in4lio/ev3dev-c) or you can write your own.

Comment: Anything in c++? I'm trying to use this within BCI2000, a C++ application suite?

Comment: @Horak Check my answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The EV3 runs on Linux w/ glibc, so you only need to upload your C programs. For C++ you need to copy over the C++ standard library. Programming like that is a bit inconvenient, as you have to mess directly with the device files.

---

The [c4ev3](http://c4ev3.github.io) bundle streamlines this. It's built around an Eclipse Plugin that includes a GCC Toolchain, an API and an integrated Uploader and File browser usable right out of Eclipse.

C and C++ Hello World template projects are included.
API and Uploader are also usable separately from Eclipse, so you can use it however you like.

Check it out :-)

---

Disclosure: I wrote part of the software.